# Sending >100 meg files to an API

Tags: rest, wcf, asp.net-web-api, streaming

We have a REST service where clients send us batch of files. These files can be quite large >100mb. We had assumed that we could do this via a REST API, but I was wonder what is considered the best practice here? We are not tied to using REST.

1. Is there a limitation on IIS and REST that would make receiving many large files untenable? Where can things go wrong?
2. Is there a best practice for REST for doing this sort of thing?
3. Are there alternatives outside of REST that are considered better?

Comment: REST is purly a convention for how to design an API using normal HTTP requests. It doesn't change in any way what HTTP can do or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/large-data-and-streaming
MaxAllowedContentLength property of IIS setting and MaxReceivedMessageSize in binding setting might be taken to consideration when transferring large data.
In short, for Intranet transfer of large files, the preferred use of Nettcpbinding in WCF provides a good performance experience, and for Internet transfer of large files, the use of async streaming may be a good idea. In addition, I don’t think that restful services have better performance than soap web services on transferring large data.